# How to set up subversion to use updates to one project in multiple visual studio solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn

I'd like to create a c# project which I want to use in multiple solutions. All of these solutions are under version control (subverion).

Is there a way to set this project up so that I can have it in only one folder in the repository to which all changes from all the different solutions (which are under verison control as well) will be commited?

My goal is that no matter in which solution anyone on our team makes a change to this project all the other solutions/projects get the update.

Comment: If you use a plug-in like Agent SVN then it and Visual Studio will manage the Subversion repository. This should then let you setup your projects as described.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it already works in that way.

When you add a Project to a Solution in `VisualStudio`, you add a *link* to that Project, and do not create a copy.

In other words, if you have a:

```
SolutionA -> ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectZ
SolutionB -> ProjectX, ProjectB, ProjectY
```

Whenever you  make some changes in `ProjectB` (which is shared between those 2 solutions) those changes will be "visible" for both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is:

1 - Have a separate repo for this C# project.
2 - Include it in your other projects using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

You can then commit changes to the C# project from any of the projects that are using it, and the next time any of the other projects does an SVN update, they will get the latest commits.